# epslatex image generated in gnuplot, how to change all fonts size when showed in latex

Tags: latex, gnuplot, font-size, pdflatex

I generated an image with gnuplot using epslatex as terminal.

```
set term epslatex "enhanced"
```

Two files are created, a .tex file and a .eps file.
When I insert the image in my LaTex document, and I build latex->pdf, everything is very nice but the fonts are too big, the following fonts:

```
1. xlabel, ylabel, zlabel
2. xtics, ytics, ztics
3. title
4. key
```

are all too big, they are basically the same size (and type) of the LaTex document (10pt).
How could I make them smaller? I am sure it is **not** changing each of them in the gnuplot file, it needs to be something in the terminal options. I tried (removing "enhanced")

```
set terminal epslatex font ',8'
```

but nothing change, same fonts as before. In the Warnings in LaTex I get:

```
pdflatex> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/enhanced/m/n' undefined
pdflatex> (Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8
```

and then also:

```
pdflatex> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

what can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following ways to control the size of the text in the plot
`set xlabel "\\begin{<size>} <your_label> \\end{<size>}"`
you can use the common `size` identifiers of LaTeX `\tiny \scriptsize \footnotesize \small \normalsize \large \Large \LARGE \huge \Huge`, which gives you control and uniformity of the font size over the whole document.
You can also use `set ylabel "\\scalebox{<factor>}{ <your_label> }"` where factor is a real number, the thing with this method is that it can be a little hard to predict the final font size without testing it several times and adjusting the value of factor.

And the double backslash is to escape the backslash itself in gnuplot

Comment: Thanks, the second method worked! I did xlabel, ylabel and zlabel. For the xtics and ytics I did:
`set ytics ("\\scalebox{0.6}{6M}" 0, "\\scalebox{0.6}{1Y}" 1, "\\scalebox{0.6}{2Y}" 2, "\\scalebox{0.6}{3Y}" 3, "\\scalebox{0.6}{4Y}" 4, "\\scalebox{0.6}{5Y}" 5, "\\scalebox{0.6}{7Y}" 6, "\\scalebox{0.6}{10Y}" 7)`
How can I do for the ztics? Those are automatic, I don't set those (they depend from the data, my data is in matrix form, just z values and fixed x and y arrays).
And also for the legend of the palette? That one has big numbers still.

Comment: You can use `format <axis> "<format specification>"` and format all the tics in one go, like this `set format y "\\scalebox{0.6}{%0.lY}"` (this one would format the ytics like the ones on your comment) or 
`set format z "\\scalebox{0.7}{%0.s}"`, you will have to play with the `Tic-mark label numerical format specifiers` so that they suit your needs, the ones in this comment are for printing integer tics, but you check them all out at [Gnuplot Docs - Format specifiers](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html)

Comment: Great! Thanks! That worked! The only thing remaining is the numbers in the colorbox (the palette), those are still big...

Comment: oh never mind I found it!
set format cb "\\scalebox{0.5}{%0.s}"
cb is for colorbox ! yeah!